# PostgreSQL: what is the difference between 0 and (0)::smallint as default?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I'm playing around with column types and default values, and came across two columns, both `smallint` but with different defaults:

1. has `0`
2. has `(0)::smallint`

When I change 2 to the value 1 has, both are the same and nothing seems changed. Of course, I googled to find the answer to my question, and found that `::` is used for type casting. But I wonder, if it is a default value, why would you need type casting?

Comment: You do not need to typecast.  Somebody did a cast in one instance but not the other when creating the table.  Try this and see:  `create table somesmallints (a smallint default 0, b smallint default 0::smallint, c smallint default (0)::smallint);`  Then do a `\d+ somesmallints`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, and the casting is not necessary.

```
# create table somesmallints (a smallint default 0, b smallint default 0::smallint, c smallint default (0)::smallint);

CREATE TABLE
# \d+ somesmallints;
                                  Table "public.somesmallints"
 Column |   Type   | Collation | Nullable |    Default    | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 a      | smallint |           |          | 0             | plain   |              | 
 b      | smallint |           |          | (0)::smallint | plain   |              | 
 c      | smallint |           |          | (0)::smallint | plain   |              | 

# select 0 = 0::smallint;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: So, basically, just put '0' as default and forget about it?

Comment: @kasimir Yes.  Just use `0`.